# Does = in a capture list of a lambda capture the this pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I currently have something like this

```
void foo::setup()
{
        //this->setSubTitleText("Summary");
        button("ok")->onPress = [=](Mtype*)
        {
            this->bar(this); //Why is the this pointer being recognized here?
        };

}
```

Does the `=` in a capture clause of a lambda give access to the `this` pointer. In my case it is ? I was under the impression to use the `this` pointer I would need to explicitly capture this like

```
        button("ok")->onPress = [=,this](Mtype*)
        {
            this->bar(this); //Why is the this pointer being recognized here?
        };
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Yes....it does.

Comment: @ChrisDrew i thought with = it only captures all of the variables from the enclosing scope by value. So it means this is also included ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) states it quite explicitly:

> Lambda capture
>
> The captures is a comma-separated list of zero or more captures,
>   optionally beginning with the capture-default. The only capture
>   defaults are
>
> & (implicitly capture the odr-used automatic variables by reference)
>   and
>
> = (implicitly capture the odr-used automatic variables by copy).
>
> **The current object (*this) can be implicitly captured if either capture
>   default is present. If implicitly captured, it is always captured by
>   reference, even if the capture default is =.**

Comment: what does odr stand for ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar odr stands for *One Definition Rule*.